# How to associate description with table fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I am designing a huge database in MySQL workbench (EER diagram) and I feel the short name of fields may not enable a programmer to recall the exact meaning and reason of creating that field. Does MySQL Workbench provide any feature to document field descriptions?

Comment: What if you make use of the comment field in the of the table? Would that be displayed in the EER diagram?

Comment: Yes Kay. You nailed it.

Comment: It's showing the comments with the field columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you make use of the comment field in the table? Would that be displayed in the EER diagram?

Here is a test table you can try with

```
CREATE TABLE `temp`.`new_table` (
  `idnew_table` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Here you can write a good explanation 
  of what the data is in this column',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnew_table`))
COMMENT = 'Here is the explanation of the table itself.';
```

Comment: Comments are not shown in the diagram, but in the associated object editors. You can also change them there.

Answer (score 0):

Use long variables, what is the problem in them. They are self explanatory. I was also a non believer of long variable name until I started programing in iOS, where tradition is to go long and make code much more readable.

This is a convenient step you can take and adopt. Commenting is a good idea but fields should also be adequate to define what they contain.

So keep a standard. Either use underscore or go with Camel notation(Leading or following). And have no issues in mind about long names. After all autocompletion will be doing half of the job.

Finally no matter you go with comments or without, do remember when the time of maintenance will come you(or anyone in place) shouldn't get stuck.